# How do I remap the arrow keys using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61486/how-do-i-change-the-controls-for-the-binding-of-isaac) about rebinding the controls for The Binding of Isaac someone suggested using AutoHotkey, and gave an example of moving wsad to edsf.  My question is how do I move the arrow keys?  Two of my arrows are broken, so I want to switch them to the keyboard.  What are the symbols for arrows in the hotkey file?

Comment: Hey there, since your question isn't really about BoI specifically, I've taken the liberty of editing it so that it doesn't look like a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I noticed the change, it looks way better.

Comment: FYI you can use the mouse to shoot.

Comment: Autohotkey is the best solution in my view. I use it with combination of capslock. For me,  the arrow keys are j, k, l and i which give me a relatively same layout as arrows keys are structured. I also mapped h for home and ; for end. This is perfect to prevent moving my hand while programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, [according to Timmy Jim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399168/how-to-use-autokey-to-keymapping#comment560811_399168), "writing scripts for key mapping software is not about gaming".

Comment: @pppery I wouldn't close due to the lack of community consensus on the matter. We have a long history of allowing [[tag:autohotkey]] questions here, dating more than 10 years ago. This should be discussed in [meta] first.

Comment: Related meta https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/should-autohotkey-and-similar-questions-geared-towards-remapping-keys-moving-cur

Answer (score 8):

The arrow keys are just called "Up" "Down" "Left" and "Right" in AHK.  A sample script to remap your arrow keys to <kbd>i</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> as up/left/down/right:

```
i::Up
j::Left
k::Down
l::Right
```

Comment: @Alex, if we solved your problem, don't forget to accept!  Click the little gray checkmark under the up/down arrows and score.  That way others know the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use arrow keys.

Basically you have to use the direction of the arrow as the key.
For example, up for up arrow.
For more information click on the link.
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80294-does-autohotkey-work-with-arrow-keys/