# How can I disable the in-game console in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

As brought up in related questions here on Arqade, the in-game console can easily disable achievements if you accidentally hit the tilde button <kbd>~</kbd>, furthermore for people who lack the self-control not to cheat, disabling the console seems like a good option.

However I can't seem to figure out how to actually disable it. Plenty of tutorials suggest setting `bAllowConsole` to `0` in various `.ini` files, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Perhaps there is a way to rebind the key from tilde to something else (like a key that doesn't exist on most keyboards?)

Comment: Gently pull out the key from keyboard. Or use [`AutoHotkey`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/110349/135338) to remap it.

Comment: @Sinatr autohotkey does not work (tried that). Also tried using disabling the key using the registry but it looks like DirectX ignores that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is much harder to solve than it should be. As you mentioned, the `bAllowConsole` does not work in FNV, so your only other option is to rebind the key. Unfortunately, binding the console to a different key is something that requires changes to the engine (for lack of better phrasing), which means you’ll need to install [a mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/63747) that uses the [New Vegas Script Extender](http://nvse.silverlock.org/) to do it.