# How can I change the controls in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

How do I change the controls/key bindings on Don't Starve? I can't play using the WASD keys.

Comment: Hi, @Toasttubby, welcome to Arqade!  I've edited your question to remove the extraneous information, and the request for when this feature will make it to the game, as that is off-topic.

Comment: If there's not an in-game way, it's probably possible to do this using AutoHotKey...  I don't own the game though, so that's more speculation than anything else.

Comment: I'd probably start with something like this - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61488/13845

Answer (score 5):

Probably wasn't available when question was asked:

From Main Menu, go to Options, Pick Controls, and you can set custom keys.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Starve is mostly controlled by mouse. You are only able to walk around using the WASD keys.

Please see below, for reference.

http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Controls

Alternatively, you could use AutoHotKey.

Comment: More recent builds include the possibility of changing controls yourself - not only to walk around, but to gather resources or hit enemies.